# Curl POST request in java with variables

Tags: java, xml, rest, curl

so I have this snip of code where I am trying to validate an xml with a certain schema using a previous web app that was developed. On the website it gave a curl command and I did some research on trying to execute it in java with no avail. I found an api called httpclient but couldn't find anything for POST

Second half of the question; if this is the correct format then it must be how I presented the xml variable in the curl command.

```
@POST
@Path("/Validate")
//Uncomment when testing with real xml
//@Produces("application/xml")
public String validate(@FormParam("xml") String xml)
{
    System.out.println(xml);
    System.out.println("validate");
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "curl -X POST --data-    urlencode 'xml=<hml>xml</hml>' http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/ ");
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String cmdXML="";
        String line=null;
        while((line=input.readLine())!=null)
        {
            cmdXML+=line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Something went wrong in validating "+ e);
        System.out.println("Error in validation");
    }
    return "stuff";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `runtime.exec(...)` requires a `String[]` when your command has more than one element.

**Java API Runtime :** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])

Second, you must ensure that command works on your side :

`curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'xml=<hml>xml</hml>' http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/`

Finally, you must indicate the full path of the command `curl`.

*Example :* `/usr/bin/curl` on Unix or `C:/Program Files/Curl/curl` on Windows

**Be careful**

On the code below, you have to replace `<PATH_TO_CURL>` by the actual path of the command `curl`

Can you try this code ?

**Code**

```
@POST
@Path("/Validate")
//Uncomment when testing with real xml
//@Produces("application/xml")
public String validate(@FormParam("xml") String xml)
{
    System.out.println(xml);
    System.out.println("validate");
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String[] command = {"<PATH_TO_CURL>/curl", "-X", "POST", "--data-urlencode", "'xml=<hml>xml</hml>'", " http://miring.b12x.org/validator/ValidateMiring/"}
        Process process = runtime.exec(command);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String cmdXML="";
        String line=null;
        while((line=input.readLine())!=null)
        {
            cmdXML+=line;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Something went wrong in validating "+ e);
        System.out.println("Error in validation");
    }
    return "stuff";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me. But I am also seeming to be having issue getting the curl command to work with a file name much less a variable in my terminal so I guess that would be the first start.

Comment: Here's an example of curl post with a file : `curl -X POST -d @file.xml http://localhost:8080/url`. If your file name is a variable, you have to replace `file.xml` with `${FILENAME}` (assuming you're on Unix machine)